# If/Else statement doesn't run inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate some input fields. More specifically, the number always has to be positive.

**EDIT: JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.error-message').hide();
  function priceCheck() {
    $('input[class="price"]').each(function() {
      priceValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(priceValue); //only runs until here and seems it exists the function then

      if (priceValue <= 0) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
      } else {

      }
    });
  }

  //POST FORM
  $("#offerInquiry").on('valid.fndtn.abide', function(evt) {
    //prevent the default behaviour for the submit event
    // Serialize standard form fields:
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var checked = $("#terms").is(":checked");
    priceCheck();


    if (checked == false) {
      $('.error-message-container').empty();
      $('.error-message-container').append("<%= pdo.translate("
        checkBox.isObligatory ") %>");
      $('.error-message').show();
      $('.bid-error').css("display", "block");
      evt.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else {
      loading();
      $.post("/inquiry.do?action=offer&ajax=1", formData,
        function(data) {
          window.top.location.href = data.redirectPage;
        });
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

I have written a function that I separately call on form submit. But it only runs until the console log. Why is the if else statement not executed?

Comment: What error do you get? Is it possible you just go into the else branch and nothing else happens?

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried `console.log("if...")` and `console.log("else...")` in your two blocks to see if it works?

Comment: post your full source

Comment: please post full code in jsfiddle

Comment: `priceValue <= 0` return `false` ?

Comment: you need to pass `evt` to `priceCheck()` like this: `priceCheck(evt);` see my answer below

Comment: I have edited the code to display the full jquery @JordanDavis

Comment: try parseInt(priceValue)

Comment: post the HTML as well so I can see it, I have a way more efficient way to achieve what your doing and will boost performance drastically.

Comment: Just leave out the `preventDefault()`, `evt` is undefined. Then do `if (priceCheck()) ...` outside the function itself to do the check.. And return true in the else statement of course. Although in this case I think you'd have to store the values and see if *all* return true.

Comment: @Shikkediel I have removed prevent default and it still does not enter the if else statement, it seems it just skips it. https://jsfiddle.net/0zjjf360/

Comment: It doesn't really skip it, it will (possibly) return false. Then for example if you do `alert(PriceCheck())` is will show 'false'. This can be used as a condition in the other function.

Comment: Hey ... I just realized it looks like you are actually injecting some server code to emit JS with the `<%= %>` block... are you using ASP or JSP or some other server scripting technology here? If so, you may need to update the practice a bit. You cannot call a server method at this point; you would need to pass the argument to that server function `pdo.translate` before emitting the JS code.

Comment: Yes @nothingisnecessary we're using JSP. No problem, I am trying to work on your solution right now. Will let you know when I figure it out and make it work completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `evt.preventDefault()` but you didn't capture the event in `evt`.

For example, you could try this instead: add the `evt` parameter to the `priceCheck` function, and then pass `evt` to that function when you call it, like this: `priceCheck(evt)`

HOWEVER, you do not need to use `preventDefault` here. You can simply return a boolean value from `priceCheck` and use that in your `submit` handler.

You also you had a couple errors with string concatentation. `$('.error-message-container').append("<%= pdo.translate(" checkBox.isObligatory ") %>");` was missing the `+` to concat those strings together . You can view errors like this in the Console tab of your JavaScript debugger. (**UPDATE** This is JSP injection, but it may not work the way you are trying to use it here. The server function `pdo.translate` will only execute once, on the server side, and cannot be called via client script... but it can emit client script. Focus on solving other problems first, then come back to this one.)

Finally, you were reading string values and comparing them to numbers. I used `parseFloat()`  to convert those values from the `input` fields into numbers.

Here is the fixed code.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.error-message').hide();

  function priceCheck() {
    var priceValid = true; // innocent until proven guilty
    $('input[class="price"]').each(function() {
      priceValue = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
      if (priceValue <= 0) {
        priceValid = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return priceValid;
  }

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    $("#offerInquiry").trigger('valid.fndtn.abide');
  });

  //POST FORM
  $("#offerInquiry").on('valid.fndtn.abide', function(evt) {
    //prevent the default behaviour for the submit event
    // Serialize standard form fields:
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var checked = $("#terms").is(":checked");
    var priceValid = priceCheck();
    if (priceValid) {
      $('.error-message').hide();
      if (checked == false) {
        $('.error-message-container').empty();
        $('.error-message-container').append("<%= pdo.translate(" + checkBox.isObligatory + ") %>");
        $('.error-message').show();
        $('.bid-error').css("display", "block");
        return false;
      } else {
        loading();
        $.post("/inquiry.do?action=offer&ajax=1", formData,
          function(data) {
            window.top.location.href = data.redirectPage;
          });
      }
    }
    else
      {
        $('.error-message').show().text("PRICE IS NOT VALID");
        }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="offerInquiry">
  Price 1
  <input type="text" class="price" id="price1" value="0.00" />
  <br/>Price 2
  <input type="text" class="price" id="price1" value="0.00" />
  <br/>
  <input type='submit' />
  <div class="error-message">ERROR!</div>
</form>
```

Comment: According to your name, `evt.preventDefault()` is not necessary. Why's everyone leaving that in...

Comment: Yes, he does not need this. However, part of the problem - and solution - was that he didn't realize he was calling `preventDefault` on an object that he didn't have... so emphasis was on passing the object `evt` to the method that was using `preventDefault` The answer is now a bit closer to best practices, and addresses each of the issues with the OP's code

Comment: Looks better with the info going in the opposite direction. You could do `if (priceCheck())` by the way.